# Internet Explorer disable/enable button. Button remains disabled until user moves his mouse on the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some troubles with yet another Internet Explorer beauty.

Scenario : I disable a button, and enable it later. Virtually, this is done, the only problem is that once my button is enabled again, it will still appear disabled to the user until he decides to move his mouse in the browser.

Any workaround this, even a dirty one ?

I use the following JQuery, although the problem exists in plain Javascript :

```
$("#processpositions_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#processpositions_button").removeAttr("disabled");
```

UPDATE : the problem happens in IE7, I suppose in IE8 as well

Comment: With jQuery since version 1.6, it's better to use ".prop()" to set element properties instead of ".attr()".  Set "disabled" to `true` to make an element disabled, and `false` to make it be enabled. This is because "disabled" is a property of the DOM node, not an attribute.

Comment: `<a href="http://getfirefox.com/">This site is best viewed with a modern browser</a>`

Comment: In what version of IE are you having this problem? I can't reproduce in IE9.

Comment: `disabled` is an HTML attribute.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1.  Still, `prop()` is a cleaner way to deal with modifying that attribute.

Comment: It's not happening in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acUpn/4/.  Consider forking that and getting your issue to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty?

The disabled attribute is basically a Boolean (false or true, 0 or 1), so try this instead:

DISABLE:

```
$("#processpositions_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

ENABLE:

```
$("#processpositions_button").attr("disabled", false);
```

---

If that helps, just use the same logic to disable the button:

```
$("#processpositions_button").attr("disabled", true);
```